# SonarQube, SonarLint and Integration Services Script tasks and components

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sonarqube, sonarlint-vs

Need to know if SonarQube and SonarLint will reach inside SQL Server Integration Services packages to perform code analysis on embedded C#/VB Script tasks and components.

Answer (score 1):

This is not planned at all. If you want to be able to analyse embedded C# or VB scripts tasks and components, you need to export their code somehow into a folder on the file system, and trigger an analysis in this folder.